# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

So I am following some tutorial on how to fetch api in react and I am using async to do so but I get the following error that the property of 0 is undefined

Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property '0' of undefined

below is my code and let me know where I went wrong

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

class GetStudents extends React.Component {
state = {
  loading:true,
  student:null
}

async componentDidMount() {
  const url = "http://localhost:3200/students";
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const data = await response.json();
  this.setState({student:data.results[0], loading:false});


}
render() {
  if (this.state.loading) {
    return <div>loading ...</div>
  }

  if (this.state.student) {
    return <div>No student was found ...</div>
  }
   return(
     <div>
         <div>{this.state.student._id}</div>
         <div>{this.state.student.role_num}</div>
         <div>{this.state.student.first_name}</div>
         <div>{this.state.student.last_name}</div>
         <div>{this.state.student.marks}</div>
     </div>
   )


}

}
export default GetStudents;
```

ok so I that error is not there any more but know I have this error
Cannot read property '_id' of undefined
and this is the url I am trying to call from http://localhost:3200/students

Comment: The parsed JSON probably doesn't have a `results` property, so trying to access `0` on that will give rise to your error. You can log `data` to see how it's structured.

Comment: please share response.json() data here

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd const data = await response.json();
  this.setState({student:data.results[0], loading:false}); is this what you wanted

Comment: Nope, I want to see your console.log(data).

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd nothing shows up in my console.log(data);

Comment: It means URL is not giving any data but you are trying to fetch data that's why it is showing an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch),

```
async componentDidMount() {
  const url = "http://localhost:3200/students";
  await fetch(url)
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((myJson) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(myJson));
    //First check what type of data you are getting here and then try to set your state as below.
    //this.setState({student:data.results[0], loading:false});
  })
  .catch(error => console.error(error)); //If error occurs you will get here
}
```

**Update**

set state in above fetch functions where you `console.log` your data using ,

```
this.setState({student:myJson, loading:false});
```

Then in render function you can iterate your state variable,

```
render() {
  if (this.state.loading) {
    return <div>loading ...</div>
  }

  if (this.state.student===null) {
     return <div>No student was found ...</div>
  }
  return(
     <div>
     {
      this.state.student.map((student)=>{
       return <> //React Fragment short syntax.
        <div>{student._id}</div>
        <div>{student.role_num}</div>
        <div>{student.first_name}</div>
        <div>{student.last_name}</div>
        <div>{student.marks}</div>
        </>
     })
    }
   </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: @ravbagul91 ok so I am getting the result in my console now I want to display it on the web page

Comment: What you are getting array or object? paste you console.log here.

Comment: [{"_id":"5d0381ad681a2a3aa1dc5873","role_num":"20","first_name":"M","last_name":"P","marks":null},{"_id":"5d10b6124adac42c4467cb88","role_num":6,"first_name":"ff","last_name":"Khan","marks":91},{"_id":"5d10b65f4adac42c4467cb89","role_num":6,"first_name":"Mohammed","last_name":"Khan","marks":91},{"_id":"5d11b586d76c463d30d02355","role_num":"97","first_name":"Mazz","last_name":"Ahadas","marks":null}]

Comment: thats what I am getting

Comment: I did the changes now I am getting this Parse Error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag

Comment: You missed the outer wrapper <div>. Wrap your code with a outer <div>. Check my updated answer.

Comment: this.state.student.map((student)=>{
  
  <div>
  {
    return <>
    <div>{student._id}</div>
    <div>{student.role_num}</div>
    <div>{student.first_name}</div>
    <div>{student.last_name}</div>
    <div>{student.marks}</div>
    </>
  }
</div>

}) I get a parsing error  @ravibagul91

Comment: Use this code - this.state.student.map((student)=>{ 
 return <> 
 <div>{student._id}</div> 
 <div>{student.role_num}</div> 
 <div>{student.first_name}</div> 
 <div>{student.last_name}</div> 
 <div>{student.marks}</div> 
 </> 
})

Comment: @Arnald I have updated the answer with the complete render function. Have a look.

Comment: @ravibadul91 that would go under the render function just to confirm and before you put this it gives me errors
{
 this.state.student.map((student)=>{
   return <> //React Fragment short syntax.
    <div>{student._id}</div>
    <div>{student.role_num}</div>
    <div>{student.first_name}</div>
    <div>{student.last_name}</div>
    <div>{student.marks}</div>
    </>
 })
}
</div>

Comment: @Arnald I have updated the answer with the complete render function. Have a look.

Comment: ok got that working now I have this Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
    at getstudents.js:20 the data is showing in the console in inspect console but I got this error

Comment: Use arrow function in `then` as I used in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

please surrounding your code with `try{...} catch{}` block, so you can see the errors if something bad happen.also I think your if is wrong so I fix it

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

class GetStudents extends React.Component {
state = {
  loading:true,
  student:null
}

async componentDidMount() {
 try{
  const url = "http://localhost:3200/students";
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const data = await response.json();
  this.setState({student:data.results[0], loading:false});
}
 catch(err){
  console.log(err)
}

}
render() {
  if (this.state.loading) {
    return <div>loading ...</div>
  }

  if (!this.state.student) { 
    return <div>No student was found ...</div>
  }
   return(
     <div>
         <div>{this.state.student._id}</div>
         <div>{this.state.student.role_num}</div>
         <div>{this.state.student.first_name}</div>
         <div>{this.state.student.last_name}</div>
         <div>{this.state.student.marks}</div>
     </div>
   )


}

}
export default GetStudents;
```

here you write

```
if (this.state.student) { 
    return <div>No student was found ...</div>
 }
```

and also you set student as null, so we must change it to :

```
if (!this.state.student) { 
    return <div>No student was found ...</div>
 }
```

Comment: I get this in my console TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at GetStudents.componentDidMount (getstudents.js:15)

Comment: @Arnald could you test you server with something like Postman or update you post with you server code ? maybe it's you server problem.